# javamail isnt sending mail by gmail?

Tags: java, android, gmail, jakarta-mail

im trying to develop an android mailbox app which would send and receive emails.
but im having issue by sending mail on javamail.

here is the codes;

ComposeMail.Java

```
package app.mailbox;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.util.Log;

public class Composemail extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String to;
    private String subject;
    private String message;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public void sendthemail(View view) {

        EditText toarea, subjectarea,messagearea;;
        toarea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_to);
        subjectarea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_sub);
        messagearea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_text);
        String to = toarea.getText().toString();
        String subject = subjectarea.getText().toString();
        String message = messagearea.getText().toString();
        try {
            GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(username, password);
            sender.sendMail(subject, message, username, to);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_composemail);
        username = Login.username;
        password = Login.password;

    }

}
```

GmailSender.java

```
package app.mailbox;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Properties;

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new app.mailbox.JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

JSSE Provider

```
package app.mailbox;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

im new to android development guys, i have no idea about why it isnt running, i also tryed debugging too but didnt find out anything.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_gmail_smtp_server.htm

also can i use this tutorial for android javamail app? or its not for android?

and i need a solution about how i can add a google autherization i mean a checking system which will check if given email and password is exist as gmail account? and i want to do that at login screen?

Comment: Only that? No more wishes?

Comment: sorry for long post but like i said, i dont have any clue why the heck it isnt working...

Comment: 1) Fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), 2) Remove ByteArrayDataSource and use [the version that comes with JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html), 3) Make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#JavaMail_for_Android), 4) If it still doesn't work, read the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ) and provide the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).